# How can I rewrite this typescript map to be more concise?

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

I have a short bit of TypeScript code that looks like the following:

```js
world.rooms = world.rooms.map((room) => {
    room = { ...defaultRoom, ...room };
    room.contents = room.contents!.map((thing) => ({
        ...defaultThing,
        ...thing,
    }));

    return room;
});
```

Basically, I have a `world` object, which has a property `rooms` which is an array of `room` objects, each of which has a `contents` property consisting of an array of `thing` objects. For each room and thing, I want to assign some default properties. The code I wrote above works correctly, but it's not very readable. Is there a more concise way to write this code?

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the `contents` bit

```
world.rooms = world.rooms.map(room => ({                                        
    ...defaultRoom, ...room,                                                    
    contents: room.contents.map(                                                
        thing => ({ ...defaultThing, thing })                                   
    )                                                                           
}));
```

Comment: You have made `room.contents` a mandatory property of rooms, If passed `room` with no `contents` array your function will throw an error. One assumes that `defaultRoom` in OPs code  would have an empty  (or some default things) `contents` array to prevent this error.